# how to export multiple objects in node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to export both the app and router instances to the server.js in node in order to serve the html page when the user request and to perform  POST request using routes.

```
        const express=require('express');
        const app = express()
        const empFinancialController = require('../controllers/empController');
        
        const router = express.Router(); 

        //serving the html page
        app.get('/addEmp',(req,res,next)=>{
        res.sendFile('./views/EmployeeManagement/addEmployee.html',{root:'./'});
    })

    //performing POST request with the DB
    router.route('/addEmp').post(empFinancialController.addNewEmployee);
    
    module.exports = router,app;
```

if i try the above way, it returns 404 error when trying to perform the post request from the client side.
and if i try the below way

```
module.exports={app,router};
```

gives me the error below

> throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' +
> gettype(fn))
> ^
> TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

below is the redirect code from the server

```
app.use('/employee/',employeeFinanceRouter);
```

please explain me how can i resolve the problem

Comment: what is `employeeFinanceRouter`? Show the code where you `require` it

Comment: const employeeFinanceRouter= require('./routes/empAndFinancilRouter'); its imported from the empAndFinancialRouter.js to the server and uses middleware to redirect the incoming requests to the router to handle all the handlers

Comment: You are exporting an object, what you should do is use the router from that object like `const employeeFinanceRouter= require('./routes/empAndFinancilRouter').router;`

Comment: `app` is an instance of `express` and not the route. What you have written doesn't make sense. you are defining a `get` method and using a `post` method. Post a new question with the complete code and the problem you are facing.

Comment: @RinkeshP found the error. As you said i have written something wrong. i tried to serve the html using `app.get()` instead of using `router.get()`. after changing it to `router.get()` its now working fine. thank you very much